# How can I modify a selection field from another class in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I want to modify the "invoice_status" field from the "SaleOrder" class asociated to an invoice after the validation of that invoice.

The validation of an invoice is defined in the "AccountInvoice" class, inside the account module:

```
@api.multi
def invoice_validate(self):
  ...
```

I realised that the "name" field from "SaleOrder" class is related with the "origin" field from "AccountInvoice" class.

So, i modified the invoice_validate function like this:

```
@api.multi
def invoice_validate(self):
    for invoice in self:
        ...
        origin = self.origin
        sale_order_id = self.env['sale.order'].search([('name', '=', origin)])[0].id
        sale_order_obj = self.env['sale.order'].browse(sale_order_id)
        sale_order_obj.write({'invoice_status': 'invoiced'})
    return self.write({'state': 'open'})
```

For some reason, the write parte doesn't work.

That is the official definition of the "invoice_status" field from SaleOrder class:

```
invoice_status = fields.Selection([
    ('upselling', 'Upselling Opportunity'),
    ('invoiced', 'Fully Invoiced'),
    ('to invoice', 'To Invoice'),
    ('no', 'Nothing to Invoice')
    ], string='Invoice Status', compute='_get_invoiced', store=True, readonly=True, default='no')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the value of invoice_status because it is a compute field. Even if you set it's value, it will be recomputed again when the field it depends on is changed and will eventually find the value it is supposed to have --and write that value instead of yours.

Odoo made it so that it work (it will say invoiced when the order is invoiced). So I don't think you need to do it maually. If you badly need to have your value stored, you should change that field so that it is not computed anymore, or create another field.

Comment: Yes, I know that the field will be recomputed again if the field it depends on is changed, but when I validate an invoice, I never will change that sale order or invoice and I want invoice_status field to have that value. Your answer clarifies me a lot. Thanks

Comment: Clicking on a button triggers a write on the record. Suppose that field in `sale.order` depends on invoice_id (a reference). It will trigger computation of that field everytime you call a write on the referenced invoice. So in that last line (`return self.write({'state'; 'open'})`) : after you write the record, the computation occurs and your value changed to the value you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `selection_add` attribute of the Selection class.

If you want to add some items to a selection field you have to redefine it in another class that inherits from the same model and declare it like this:

```
invoice_status = fields.Selection(selection_add=[("state", "open")])
```

Check the Selection class documentation and search for `selection_add` in your codebase to see some examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not the point. I don't want to add new items to selection field. I want to modify it with another value of its own values. Avoid the part of the return, it is confusing you. I want to set the value "invoiced" (which exists already) to the "invoice_status" field.